# Proving that $d_{TV}(X,Y) \leq P(X \neq Y)$ (Total Variation Distance)

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, metric-spaces

Let $X,Y$ denote integer valued random variables and consider the total variance distance
$$
d_{TV}(X,Y) = \sup_{A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})} \vert P(X \in A) - P(Y \in A) \vert.
$$
**I want to prove that $d_{TV}(X,Y) \leq P(X \neq Y)$.**

---

I have managed to prove (as a preliminary result) that

$$
2d_{TV}(X,Y) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \vert P(X=k) - P(Y=k) \vert
$$

which I think may be useful since an idea could be to somehow intersect with the event that $X \neq Y$. But I am not quite sure how to get there and even how an upperbound would appear.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4673331/43949

Comment: Yes it does, thank you! I will refrain from deleting the question as the linked question is hard to find if like me you look at it from the angle of total variance distance.